# how can i get all number of chatting whats in my android app

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I  need to get all numbers has been chatting with me on whats to my android app Regardless of  this number of my contact or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this to be honest, it would be need an content provider implemenation on whatsapp side, i didn't found related on whats documentation

Comment: but, i found some apps do it that ..!